# FilterBy using column doesn't work in primefaces 5.3

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2

Here is the source code of my .xhtml file when the datatable appears i try to filter by id in olumn it doesn't work.
I have looked for the solution and i found that there is another mechanism in primefaces 5.3 that i don't understand please if you can help me. I'm newbie to primesfaces and JSF
Thank you

```
<p:column  filterBy="#{student.id}" filterMatchMode="contains">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Id" />
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{student.id}" />
            </p:column>
```

Comment: There's no problem with the `filterBy` field in PF. Check if you have the table wrapped into an `h:form`.

Comment: I am assuming you went through the PrimeFaces showcase here: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/filter.xhtml

Comment: @Erick, exactly iwent through it. but in vain

Comment: @XtremeBiker thank you i wrapped it with h:form i think the problem is just in the code posted

Comment: I see nothing wrong with the code posted. Check out your server/browser logs for any exception being thrown.